# A Vertical Navigation Bar Moving to The Top

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

I'm trying to make my vertical navigation bar to move to the top when the user scrolls (the original position is not at the top).
I only know HTML, CSS and JavaScript, so I don't know jQuery.
Here is the code for the navigation bar:

Is there something wrong with the class or id names or is it the JavaScript code?

```js
 

 var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
 var navigation = document.getElementById("navigation");
 window.addEventListener("scroll", navigationFixing());
 function navigationFixing() {
  if (body.scrollTop > navigation.getBoundingClientRect().bottom)
  {navigation.className = "fixedNavigation";
 }
  else {
   navigation.className = "notFixedNavigation";
  }
 }
```

```css
#navigation {list-style-type: none;
 width: 15%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-size: 35px;
 border: 1px solid;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #d6d6c2;
 overflow: auto;
 position: absolute;
 }
.navigationbar {
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 }
.navigationbar a {display: block;
   background-color: #C0C0C0; 
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #ffffff;
   }
.navigationbar a:hover {background-color: #404040;
   color: white;}   
.navigationbar a.nuvarande {background-color: black; 
}

.fixedNavigation {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
.notFixedNavigation {
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navigation" class="notFixedNavigation">
   <li class="navigationbar">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
   </li>
   <!---------------DATOR-------------------
   <li class="navigationbar">
    <a href="play.html">Play</a>
   </li>
   ---------------------------------------->
   <li class="navigationbar">
    <a href="" class="nuvarande">Rules</a>
   </li>
   <li class="navigationbar">
    <a href="tactics.html">Tactics</a>
   </li>
   <li class="navigationbar">
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: For #navigation you also specified position:absolute which will overwrite the one in css class since it’s higher importance.. Either remove it or add position: fixed !important; to .fixedNavigation class

Answer (score 0):

You care calling your event handler immediately, instead of attaching it to the listener. Remove the parens.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", navigationFixing);
```

In addition, `navigation.getBoundingClientRect().bottom` will change when the position changes. Better to set it outside the function.

```
var pos = navigation.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
function navigationFixing() {
  if (body.scrollTop > pos) {...}
}
```

Also note from @bestinamir, your CSS is being overwritten. It needs some work, but you can start with:

```
.fixedNavigation {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```